# Convert Eorzea DateTime value to Earth time

Tags: c#, datetime, time

A while ago I posted the following, which was gladly answered by olitee (all credit goes to him for the solution):

[Convert DateTime value to Final Fantasy XIV Eorzea Game Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944108/convert-datetime-value-to-final-fantasy-xiv-eorzea-game-time)

I was trying to add features to my code and one would require to be able to put that Eorzea time (FFXIV) back to Earth time for alerts.

The following code, provided by olitee, was converting Earth time to Eorzea time just fine:

```
public static class EorzeaDateTimeExtention
{
    public static DateTime ToEorzeaTime(this DateTime date)
    {
        const double EORZEA_MULTIPLIER = 3600D/175D;

        long epochTicks = date.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks);

        long eorzeaTicks = (long)Math.Round(epochTicks * EORZEA_MULTIPLIER);

        return new DateTime(eorzeaTicks);
    }
}
```

How would I achieve the opposite? I tried to revert the mathematical calculations but apparently it keeps giving me negative epochTicks which results in error whenever I try the conversion.

Apparently I am missing something or I got it wrong at some point.

My understanding of the ticks is quite limited.

Any help and/or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What do you have as an input and what do you want as a result?

Comment: Greetings, I generate the Eorza time and then parse it to get the year-month-day and then add a specific hour, let's say 07:00, then I want that converted to 2016-06-06 03:01:00 (default DateTime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ToEarthTime` method should give you the earth time.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var ff = now.ToEorzeaTime();
        Console.WriteLine($"Now: {now} | FF: {ff}");

        var ffNew = new DateTime(ff.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var nowNew = ffNew.ToEarthTime();
        Console.WriteLine($"Now: {nowNew} | FF: {ffNew}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class Converter
{
    private const double EORZEA_MULTIPLIER = 3600D / 175D;

    public static DateTime ToEorzeaTime(this DateTime date)
    {

        long epochTicks = date.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks);

        long eorzeaTicks = (long)Math.Round(epochTicks * EORZEA_MULTIPLIER);

        return new DateTime(eorzeaTicks);
    }

    public static DateTime ToEarthTime(this DateTime date)
    {
        var epochTicks = (long) Math.Round(date.Ticks/EORZEA_MULTIPLIER);
        var earthTicks = epochTicks + new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks;
        var utc = new DateTime(earthTicks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return utc.ToLocalTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: Greetings, thanks a lot for the help and the code, this is what I was looking for and it's greatly appreciated. My main problem is that I did not change the - to a + in the ticks calculation (eorzeaTicks vs earthTicks). Thanks again!